# Improving this Component Architecture

Tags: javascript, typescript, architecture, immutable.js

I'm using Immutable.js and Typescript to build an entity component system for a game I'm working on. Right now I'm trying to flesh out the semantics of how components are created. My current design is a bit more repetitive than I'd like, so I'm looking for ways to improve it.

One of the main roadblocks is that I really want my components to be immutable. Changing them should result in a new instances, but I'm having trouble finding ways to actually enforce this statically.

## Component Base Class

```
/**
 * @file game/Component.ts
 */

/**
 * All possible component types. Used for serialization
 */
export enum ComponentType {
    OCCUPANCY
};

/**
 * Components are used to make entities interesting. Components provide almost
 * all of the core game functionality from basic movement to unique items.
 * Components are completely independent and should primarily contain data,
 * NOT behavior.
 */
export abstract class Component {
    /**
     * The id of this component
     * @type {ComponentID}
     */
    public readonly id: ComponentID;
    /**
     * The type of this component
     * @type {ComponentType}
     */
    public readonly type: ComponentType;

    constructor(type: ComponentType, id: ComponentID) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

## Example Component

```
/**
 * @file game/components/Occupancy.ts
 * Describes the occupancy status of a grid cell
 */

import { ComponentType, Component, ComponentID } from "../Component"
import { Entity } from "../Entity"

import { Record } from "immutable"

export type OccupancyStatus = Entity | "free" | "unknown"

export type OccupancyParams = {
    status?: Entity | "free" | "unknown"
};

export const OccupancyRecord = Record({
    status: "unknown"
});

class OccupancyData extends OccupancyRecord {
    /**
     * The occupancy status of this entity
     * @type {OccupancyStatus}
     */
    status: OccupancyStatus;
    /**
     * Construct a new state with the given parameters
     * 
     * @param {OccupancyParams} params Parameters to use instead of defaults
     */
    public constructor(params?: OccupancyParams) {
        params ? super(params) : super();
    } 
    /**
     * Create a new OccupancyData with the same values as this one except as
     * indicated by the provided values
     * @param  {OccupancyParams} values Values to replace in the new instance
     * @return {OccupancyData}          New instance
     */
    public with(values: OccupancyParams): OccupancyData {
        return this.merge(values) as this;
    }
}

export class Occupancy extends Component {
    public readonly data: OccupancyData;

    constructor(id: ComponentID, params?: OccupancyParams) {
        super(ComponentType.OCCUPANCY, id);

        this.data = new OccupancyData(params);
    }

    public with(values: OccupancyParams): Occupancy {
        const new_data = this.data.with(values);

        return new Occupancy(this.id, new_data);
    }
}
```

As you can see this is pretty repetitive. I have to enumerate all properties of a component 3 times per component definition: once for the Params struct, once for defining the record defaults, and once for adding accessors. Additionally, there's nothing really enforcing that components follow this structure or make themselves immutable which smells funny to me.

Comment: There's a lot going on here so it might be hard to give recommendations. Is it necessary to be using ImmutableJS? You could just trust yourself to avoid mutations.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to cut it down as much as possible. The fact that there's a lot going on is sort of what I'm trying to fix. It's not necessary to use that library or immutability in general I suppose, but I'm sort of anal when it comes to good interfaces/design so this kind of stuff bugs me.